# Simple program to cut videos without ANY loss of quality for Windows, Linux or Android

Tags: video, video-editing

I need a program to **cut videos** (extract a sub-video from them), but I absolutely need there will be **no quality losses at all** from the original.

As long as I don't need to do anything more (like editing, resizing, rotating, adding subtitles, colorize etc.), I prefer this program to be very easy to manage. Ideal case would be just setting *start* capture, *end* capture, and a button to *split*.

I have tested [Allok Video Splitter](http://www.alloksoft.com/splitter.htm), but I am sure there are some (not much, but they exist) degradations in video quality (audio keeps OK, or so it seems), even when I set the program to maximum quality.

**Open source** method preferred.
**Command-line** methods accepted.
**Windows** or **Linux** platform, please. I have no Mac. No problem to do this on **Android**, as long as the main feature (no quality loss) remains.

Comment: Check out this question on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video ... It's perhaps a little out of date, but you might be able to answer your own question with this information :-)

Comment: Actually, this is even more applicable to your question: http://superuser.com/questions/377343/cut-part-from-video-file-from-start-position-to-end-position-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would suggest using the command line and [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) as in:

`ffmpeg -ss` *start_time* `-i` *input_file* ***.ext*** `-t` *duration* `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` *output_file* ***.ext***

- ***.ext*** must be a supported video type and the same in both cases *note there should be no space between the name and .ext it is only there above to get the bold and italic to work*.
- `-ss` should be before the input file, *this allows the last keyframe before your start time to be selected* and **must** be before `-t`
- Where both *start_time* and *duration* can be either a number of seconds, minutes:seconds, hours:minutes:seconds and  *both minutes & seconds limited to 2 digits in any colon format* and any seconds can have .milliseconds attached.
- `-vcodec copy -acodec copy` informs ffmpeg that you would like exactly the same video and audio encoding, i.e. no loss of quality.

Also note that since ffmpeg works in what is known as a pipeline **the order of most options is very significant** so if your output file name occurs before some of your options they will be assumed to be options for the next stage in the pipeline and so will not affect your output image.  This is done so that you can specify on a single command line one input file and several output files with different options so that you could, for example, generate a sequence of 10 second clips each 5 minutes apart ready to recombine them.

This solution is:

- Free/Gratis
- Open Source
- No change in quality *unless you ask for it*
- If you need to you *can* change format, resolution, order, add still frames, just about anything.
- Windows, Linux & Mac
- *You do need to find your times for splitting and make a note of them manually but that shouldn't be too much of a stretch*.

There are a number of GUI front ends available for ffmpeg, *and a lot of programs that don't mention that all they really do is provide one*, but why bother for a simple operation like this.

Example command that worked for the OP:

```
ffmpeg -i OriginalVideo.flv -ss 1:00 -t 3:00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy OutputFile.flv
```

*Thanks to Sopalajo de Arrierez for taking some time to experiment and posting what worked for them.*

Comment: Thanks, @Steve, but what do you mean when you say «input_file and output_file both have the same name»? That is not possible. Did you mean «same extension»?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - exactly that - I'll edit.

Comment: Tested `ffmpeg.exe -i "PathToFile.flv" -ss 01:00 "PathToNewFile.flv" -t 01:00` from Windows 7 in order to extract from minute 1 to minute 2 of a .flv video. The result file has a great quality loss, easy to perceive at first sight.

Comment: Tested adding `-vcodec copy -acodec` with same results: quality degrades.

Comment: Finally solved. This is the line that did it: `ffmpeg -i OriginalVideo.flv -ss 1:00 -t 3:00 -vcodec copy -acodec copy OutputFile.flv`. I suggest for you to edit your answer. Maybe you could mention the examples: `.flv` for file format (must be the same for output file!), starting at minute 1, 0 seconds, duration 3 minutes (180 seconds). IMPORTANT: the parameters must be specified prior to the output file; anything wroten after it will be ignored by `ffmpeg`. That was my problem (maybe you could detail it too).

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez - Updated answer - thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion, as long as the speed of the cutting allows you to be sure that recoding did not happen.Note that `-c copy`  seems to be an alias for `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`, so it can be used instead.

Comment: There is a typo (twice) in the syntax specification: a space between the file name and `.ext`.

Comment: The good deal with using `ffmpeg` is the detailed info, like `Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)` that certifies there was no quality change.

Comment: Another suggestion, Steve: as stated here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking , it has worked better for me to specify `-ss timestart` before `-i input_file.ext`, because it sets (or so I understand) the beginning of the generated video to the nearest keyframe found before your specified timestamp. If later specified, the first second(s) of your resulting video could have some delay. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005110/how-to-split-a-video-using-ffmpeg-so-that-each-chunk-starts-with-a-key-frame . Tested on `.flv` and `.mp4` files.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez The typo was needed to allow the italics and bold - a limitation of SO/markdown if I tried `*name***.ext**` it came out with the stars in. I thought it better to have the clarity than something that could be pasted but needed editing anyway. Adding a note.

Comment: Works very good, except that audio gets out of sync. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @bytecode77 I have same problem that `audio gets out of sync`, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

What you're looking for is [**AviDemux**](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/).

**AviDemux** is an open-source GUI video processing software made in Linux which also has releases for Windows (x86 and x64), it also has a command-line version called **avidemux_cli.exe** which comes inside the package.

It can perform re-conversion of various formats and also it can perform copy/cut/paste operations with no re-conversion, this means 0% quality is lost during the procedure because is just a remux operation.

It has a very user-friendly UI, and works perfect for cut/split a video once or at various points, as I said, with no reconversion unless you specify the opposite.

[image: AviDemux interface]

I love **AviDemux**, you will love it too. Download it here:

http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/download.html

Comment: Tested latest v2.6.10 64 bits to extract 4 minutes from a 5 minutes `.flv` video: the result is a `.avi` file that has the audio but no video at all.

Comment: @Sopalajo de Arrierez If you are working with an FLV video then try select the **FLV Muxer** instead of **AVI Muxer** in the "Output Format" list.

Comment: http://www.fosshub.com/Avidemux.html/avidemux_2.6.13_win64.exe doesn't work

Comment: Same issue as @SopalajodeArrierez. Matched audio/video codecs input and output.

Comment: Use `up` and `down` to move between keypoints and select segments for deletion with `ctrl+pgup/down` to allow Avidemux to save without reencoding.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to **complete** the other answers by referring this solution of mine on another thread that seems to solve the **audio sync** and beginning of **frames frozen** issues for `ffmpeg` :

[The key frame issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33188399/1461017)

The (curious) solution is just on **typing** the `-ss` parameter **before** the `-i` one.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [VideoReDo](http://www.videoredo.com/) for Windows.  You mark start and end and click cut.
When your done cutting click save and save it in the orginal format.

Comment: Would this tool really convert without any loss at all? All I have tested for now (`ffmpeg` included) degradate the quality.

Comment: The only true way to edit is to convert it to an uncompressed AVI.  Then as long as it remains so it will never degrade.  However, except the file size to increase by a factor of 100x.

Comment: "True way to edit?". I don't need to edit the video. The question is about just cutting.

Comment: Let me rephrase.  The only way to get 100% loss less cuts in AVI uncompressed.  99.9% of compression techniques use parts of the data from the previous frame in the next frame.    When you **cut** a chunk out the 2 frames, 1 on either side of the edit, are modified and a tiny amount of loss occurs.  Only single frame compression methods will be 100% unmodified.  As far those techniques were lost to time.  However, uncompressed AVI is just that uncompressed, and each frame is independent of each other so when you cut it no loss occurs, and its uncompressed so no loss there either.

Comment: ffmpeg has dozens of settings and you can get results with the correct settings.  However, a very tiny amount is lost at the cut points, unless you have loss less or uncompressed files.  If you convert your file to AVI uncompressed and save it that way when your done any video editor can edit it 100% loss less.

Comment: Some lost at the cut points is okay. Say I want no loss on the rest?

Comment: The comment about uncompressed AVIs being the only format to allow 100% lossless cuts is misleading.  MP4s can certainly also allows lossless cuts at keyframes.

Comment: @AlexPeters  Often waiting for the next key frame isn't always precise enough.  However, if a video editor wanted to, they could automatically find the previous key frame, and all the frames up to the actually cut point.  Then on the end of the video cut they could again rewind to the previous cut frame and all subsequent frames till the cut point.  Possibly creating new key frames, and resulting in the perfect cut.  However, I don't know that any of them actually do this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Losless-cut](https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut). It uses keyframe cutting.

(+) Windows

(+) Linux

**(-) Android**